# $GET regarding filenames and paths (security related)

Tags: php, security, get

I made a simple download script this afternoon as shown below.

Basically I pass `file='whatever.something'` to it and presents the download to the user.

I started thinking about security afterwards... since anyone can pass their own variables if they know the url of the page... do I need to worry about anything here?

Is it possible for someone to pass something like `'../../../../something` and actually go back to my `/home/` directory where they could download any file they want?

```
if(isset($_GET['file']))
{
    $file = '/home/test/user-data/'.$_SESSION['user']['account_id'].'/downloads/'.$_GET['file'];

    if(file_exists($file))
    {
        //get current ts
        $now = time();

        //set headers
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type:  application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$now.'_file.csv');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file).'');

        //download
        readfile($file);
        //delete it
        unlink($file);  
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not only possible, but a matter of time (hours or days) until someone tries.

Comment: Figured... any recommendations?  Outside of making a specific file for each file with no $GET is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: you can filter out paths containing `..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something along the lines of :

```
if(isset($_GET['file'])) 
{
    // sanitize request and keep just the name and extension
    $file_path  = $_GET['file'];
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
    $file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
    $file_ext   = $path_parts['extension'];

    // replaces the file location with a preset one
    $file_path  = '/home/test/db-backups/'.$file_name;

    // make sure the file exists
    if (is_file($file_path))
    {
            .....
```